# Pygame game menu issues

Tags: python, menu, pygame

So I am making a game in Pygame and I need a menu to let the player choose between different game types. I tried to make it so that when the instructions are shown, the player can use the keyboard to choose the type; however, the game bugs out when I do this. The instructions will remain on the screen (sometimes the plane sprite will be drawn in). I added a line of code to print something in the shell when `'e'` was pressed, but nothing prints.

```
def instructions(score):
    pygame.display.set_caption("Mail Pilot!")

    plane = Plane()
    ocean = Ocean()

    allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group(ocean, plane)
    insFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
    insLabels = []
    instructions = (
    "Mail Pilot.     Last score: %d" % score ,
    "Instructions:  You are a mail pilot,",
    "delivering mail to the islands.",
    "",
    "Fly over an island to drop the mail,",
    "but be careful not to fly too close",    
    "to the clouds. Press 'e' for",
    "endless",
    "",
    "good luck!",
    "",
    "click to start, escape to quit..."
    )

    for line in instructions:
        tempLabel = insFont.render(line, 1, (255, 255, 0))
        insLabels.append(tempLabel)

    keepGoing = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    while keepGoing:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                keepGoing = False
                donePlaying = True
                pygame.display.quit()
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
##            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
##                keepGoing = False
##                donePlaying = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                    gameType = "endless"
                    keepGoing = False
                    donePlaying = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    keepGoing = False
                    pygame.display.quit()
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                    donePlaying = True

        allSprites.update()
        allSprites.draw(screen)

        for i in range(len(insLabels)):
            screen.blit(insLabels[i], (50, 30*i))

        pygame.display.flip()

    plane.sndEngine.stop()    
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
    return donePlaying

def main():
    gameType = ""
    donePlaying = False
    score = 0
    while not donePlaying:
        donePlaying = instructions(score)
        if not donePlaying:
            if gameType == "endless":
                score = gameEndless()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The commented out part is the original code that would start the game.

Comment: you have to clear screen in every loop - ie `screen.fill(BLACK)` or `blit(background)`.

Comment: you have two local variables with name `gameType` - first in `main()`, second in `instructions()`. You have to use `return donePlaying, gameType` to return this value from `instructions()` to `main()`

Comment: or you can use dictionary for config - `config ={'gameType': "", "score": 0}` and then `instructions(config)`, `gameEndless(config)` and you will no need `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @furas for helping me realize the problem!

To fix the program, I added a direct call to the game from the if loop in the instructions class.

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                    gameType = "endless"
                    keepGoing = False
                    donePlaying = False
                    score = gameEndless()
```

and then returned the score at the bottom

```
return donePlaying, score
```

The main loop no longer calls the game, but instead just calls on instruction when donePlaying is True

```
def main():
    donePlaying = False
    score = 0
    while not donePlaying:
        donePlaying = instructions(score)
```

This way, I can circumvent the main loop issues and add a more streamlined approach instead of bouncing between main, intructions, and game types.

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another reason I despise the "omni-applicable" event driven programming. Though it seems you have found a solution, I believe the best way of finding the mousex and mousey is simply to call

```
mousex,mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

outside of the event loop. Though of course MOUSEBUTTONUP is suitable for its usage, the finding of the mouse coordinates is simply not something that needs to be event based in this context.